# Django generic ListView two models

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In django template i need to iterate over two models with two different information but doing nested loops `for` inside `for` think that is wrong. 
In addition this code in template does not work. I created two views that references to the same template.

**template**    Inside each module should be it's own childs.

```
{% if all_modules %}
{% for module in all_modules %}
    <li><a class="scrollto" href="">{{ module.name }}</a>
    <ul class="nav doc-sub-menu v">
        {% for child in all_childs %}
        <li><a class="scrollto" href="#step1">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor%}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <li><a class="scrollto" href="">None</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

In views

```
class BackendModulesListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'backend_modules.html'
    model = BackendModules
    context_object_name = 'all_modules'

class ChildsListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'backend_modules.html'
    model = Child
    context_object_name = 'all_childs'
    queryset = Child.objects.filter(backend_modules_id=1)
```

In models

```
class Child(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     backend_modules = models.ForeignKey(BackendModules, null=True, blank=True,
                                             related_name='backend')
     frontend_components = models.ForeignKey(FrontendComponents, null=True, blank=True,
                                                 related_name='frontend')
```

Please help me to find solution and optimize code. I know i write bad code :(

Comment: Are you trying to iterate `all_modules` and `all_childs` simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what i understood you are trying to iterate all_modules and for every instance in the all_modules you are trying to iterate all_childs inside it. to do that you dont need to create 2 views since you can use ForeignKey reverse relationship. so your template should look something like that :

## backend_modules.html

```
{% if all_modules %}
{% for module in all_modules %}
    <li><a class="scrollto" href="">{{ module.name }}</a>
    <ul class="nav doc-sub-menu v">
        {% for child in module.child_set.all %}
        <li><a class="scrollto" href="#step1">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor%}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <li><a class="scrollto" href="">None</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked